# AJAX not working in IE7

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

We have a lot of AJAX in our pages. Mostly it's been in our internal systems, so we haven't tested it with a lot of browsers. But at the moment we're developing a major feature, that will use AJAX, for our customers and we testing it more thoroughly. One of the tests have been in IE9 running IE7 mode, which worked just fine. But when we took a machine running a real IE7 browser, we discovered that AJAX only works once on any of our pages. It seems that after a part of the page is re-rendered with ajax, all javascript events in the part of the HTML that was re-rendered stops working. It's impossible to get even a javascript alert() box to appear.

**Since we only have one machine with IE7, we would like to know if anyone can verify that this is a real problem, and not just a problem with this one machine of ours?**

**And if it is a real problem, what did you do to fix it?** 10 % of our users still use IE7, so cutting that browser just isn't a workable solution.

**UPDATE / SOLVED:**
We decided to get a new server and set it up with Windows XP. Even though we don't support it, we tested it in IE6 and it worked. Then we installed IE7 and it worked too. Guess our old test server is all messed up some how. So all works in IE7 after all.

Thank you for the suggestions all.

Comment: PS: We're using JSF2 and f:ajax for all our AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I intend to forget about older browsers, but I usually use the **jQuery library** for my AJAX requests since I usually use `jQuery` anyway for specific animations etc.

jQuery supports these browsers:

> Firefox 3.6, 5.0.x, 6.0.x
>
> Internet Explorer 6+
>
> Safari 5.0.x Opera Current - 1
>
> version Chrome Current - 1 version

[source](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility)

Because jQuery AJAX is very much part of the jQuery library as anything else, I assume that the jQuery AJAX is supported by these browsers as well.

[jQuery AJAX API](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

AJAX calls are cached in IE. Use "cache: false" in the ajax call options.

Comment: What would happen if you didn't use "cache: false"?

Comment: I mean, we click a submit button and AJAX fires. Then we click it again and no onclick events fire. Instead a traditional non-AJAX POST request is sent.

Comment: If you don't add "cache: false", IE will cache your ajax calls and you won't get new data from the server

Comment: I will see if I can test this somehow, but I must say, I have my doubts about this. It's because the first AJAX request always works for us. After that request and new HTML has been rendered, any JS event in the new HTML fails to fire. Even something like this: onclick="alert('test');" on a non-AJAX element will do nothing. I have difficulties connecting that behavior with a cache problem. But I will look into it anyhow, because I'm out of ideas myself and open to any suggestions by now.

Comment: If new HTML gets rendered, you're right, it's not a caching problem.

Comment: @Bjørn Could you verify that all javascript resources are correctly loaded after the first ajax request is finished? Are there any errors reported in the IE dev tools for missing resources (something like 'mojarra is not defined')?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Turned out there is a problem with our test server.